# Finding probability distribution function when given a different continuous random variable.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

**Question:**

> The continuous random variable $T$ is distributed uniformly on the interval $[2, 4].$
> Given that $V = \sqrt{2T - 7}$  find the probability distribution function for $V.$

So far I've been able to do the following:

$P(T = t) = 0.5$, $P(T \leq t) = 0.5t - 1$

Rearrange and plug in from $P(T<=t)$:

$P(V<=v)= P(\sqrt{2T-7} \leq v) = P(T\leq (v^2+7)/4) = 0.5(\frac{v^2+7}2) - 1 $

$ = \frac{1}4v^2+\frac{3}4$

Given that the limits of t are between 2 and 4, from my understanding, the limits of v should then be $ 0\leq v\leq 1$, since $ \sqrt{4 \cdot 2 - 7} = 1$.

However, this means than if I plug in $v = 0$ into my equation $P(V \leq v) = \frac{1}4v^2+\frac{3}4$, I get $P(V\leq v) = \frac{3}4 $, which is wrong.

However, I'm not sure where I have gone wrong in my working,



Any help would be appreciated,

Many thanks

Comment: Since $T\in[2,4]$ we have $2T-7\in [-3,1].$ So how are you treating $\sqrt{2T-7}$ when $2T-7<0?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm not exactly sure how to deal with $2T-7 < 0$ other than to ignore it, because I assumed that they are not asking you to use i or anything.

Comment: Not clear what “ignore it” means. Without knowing what to do when $2T-7<0,$ you can’t know anything about $V.$ $2T-7<0$ with probability $3/4.$

Comment: Apologies, I'm stuck as to how to deal with then $2T - 7 < 0$. I'd guess I either need to use i or split the probability into 2 equations, but I don't know what that looks like. @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is not "well-defined." It is neither continuous nor discrete. If $3.5<T<4$, then $f(v)=2v, 0<v<1$. This integrates to 1. But it doesn't make sense to say that 1/4 of the time, V has this pdf, and the other 3/4 of the time, V is undefined, because it is T that lies in 3.5<T<4 1/4 the time, but this doesn't mean that the pdf of V will be that 1/4 the time; in fact, it is always that when V has certain values. Or if you made it proportional to the actual probability, then $f(v)=\frac v 2, 0<v<1$, but what would you do with values outside this range. They would have to be 0. But then this isn't a pdf, and also doesn't tell you when V is undefined.